# Skip a middleware and go to route

Tags: node.js, express

How to skip the middleware and go to the routes?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.originalUrl === '/login') {
    // How to skip the auth middleware and continue the routes?
    ??
  }

  next();
});

// auth middleware
app.use(acl.auth);

app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: Why are you testing req.body.user ? The clients can send what they want there

Comment: Based on the posted code, you have defined [`Application-level`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) middleware. This means any request coming to your app will have to go through `acl.auth`. Maybe you should take a look at [`Router-level`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) middleware to determine authentication? Or modify your `acl.auth` middleware to do what you want.

Comment: I have change the code. Is there anyway to skip the auth middleware, because some route may not need auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As they pointed out `acl.auth` will be fired for every request.
2. Why are you using two middlewares to check authentication?
3. req.body.user is not good. Save the user in request or in session.

Answering to your question, you can do something like that:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (typeof req.user !== 'undefined') {
    // Define a variable in request
    req.isAuthenticated = true;
    next();
  }

  next();
});
```

And in your acl.auth you can check that variable.

```
if(req.isAuthenticated) next();
```

### EDIT

Also you can skip the middleware by not using `app.use()`.
For example:
Routes with auth required:

```
app.get(acl.auth, function(req, res){});
```

Routes without auth required:

```
app.get(function(req, res){});
```

Comment: I have change my code, it is to skip auth if the route is login.